# wrapping json object in another object

Tags: python, json

this is in Python

I have a json object with several rows in

```
[{obj1: "stuff", obj2: "more stuff"}]
```

I would now like to add a name to this array so it will look like

```
rows: [{obj1: "stuff", obj2: "more stuff"}]
```

The code so far is not working

```
df = self.db.load_data_select(sql)
row = json.loads('row: {}')

js = df.to_json(orient='records')
row = json.loads(js)
```

Comment: Arrays don't have names; any code that tries to give an array a name will *never* work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing and fixing.

Load the dataset into pandas in this case. Convert it to dictionary. Add in the dictionary of columns.

Then create the final dictonary with all the parts that want. The will then "wrap" the content into the data object. Then dump it back as a json object with json.dumps(). Return the data to the flask api.

```
row = {"data": {"columns": columns, "rows": js }}
```

Full code

```
    df = self.db.load_data_select(sql)

    js = df.to_dict(orient='records')

    columns = [{
        "label": 'Fall',
        "field": 'Fall',
        "sort": 'asc',
        "width": 150
      },
      {
        "label": 'Region',
        "field": 'Region',
        "sort": 'asc',
        "width": 150
      },
      {
        "label": 'Datum',
        "field": 'save_time',
        "sort": 'asc',
        "width": 150
      }]

    print(js)
    row = {"data": {"columns": columns, "rows": js }}
    # row["data"]["rows"].append(js)


    js2 = json.dumps(row, default=self.default)
    return js2
```